# Dimensional analysis of projectile in nonuniform gravitational field (high altitude projectile)

Tags: dimensional-analysis, projectile-motion

A well-understood dimensional analysis of the highest point of the projectile in a uniform gravitational field goes like

$$
[x_M] = [g^av_0^bm^c]\\
L = (\frac{L}{T^2})^a(\frac{L}{T})^bM^c
$$

Equating the dimensions of both sides yields
$$
a+b=1\\
-2a-b=0\\
c=0\\
$$

Then we have $x_M\sim\frac{v_0^2}{g}$

But how do we carry this analysis to nonuniform field, namely, $g^* = g\frac{R^2}{(x+R)^2}$, where R is the planetary radius.

Comment: Here I simply wrote $x_M=\frac{v_0^2}{g}F(\Pi)$ for some dimensionless $\Pi$ on my notebook. I really can't think of other ways $\textit{differenciate}$ it from the uniform case. The explicit solution for high altitude projectile is rather complicated.